# Is the melt function the right function to use? I want to reorganize my columns and rows in R

Tags: r, variables, casting, melt, columnsorting

I was hoping to get some help reorganizing my data table.

Right now I have a data table that looks something like this (this is fake data):

```
city       year  income_per_capita
Boston     1998       21344.32
Boston     1999       23454.45
Boston     2000       21628.31
London     1998       31526.23
London     1999       36889.56
London     2000       34521.12
Chicago    1998       25643.30
Chicago    1999       21452.24
Chicago    2000       23465.35
```

I want to make it look like this

```
          1998        1999         2000

Boston   21344.32    23454.45      21628.31
London   31526.23    36889.56      34521.12
Chicago  25643.30    21452.24      23465.35
```

I was told to try the `melt()` function, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm very new to R. I tried using `id.vars` and `variable.name` but I still can't get it to where I want it to be.

Thank you and please let me know if I can provide more details!

Comment: you should use `dcast`, `dcast(df, city ~ year, value.var = 'income_per_capita')`

Comment: Thank you so much! It did the job perfectly.